# How to access the attribute of a parent node using F# Data's XML Type Provider?

Tags: xml, f#, parent, f#-data, xmldataprovider

How to access the attribute of a parent node using [F# Data's XML Type Provider](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/XmlProvider.html)? Let's say I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<ROOT>
    <level1 name="level1Name1" x="8">
        <level2 name="level2Name1" a="8" b="104" />
        <level2 name="level2Name2" a="85" b="140" />
    </level1>
    <level1 name="level1Name2" x="10">
        <level2 name="level2Name3" a="50" b="500" />
        <level2 name="level2Name4" a="376" b="1065" />
        <level2 name="level2Name5" a="10" b="100" />
        <level2 name="level2Name6" a="700" b="700" />
    </level1>
    <level1 name="level1Name3" x="7">
        <level2 name="level2Name7" a="502" b="66" />
    </level1>
</ROOT>
```

And I want to use it in the below code:

```
open System
open System.Xml.Linq
open FSharp.Data

type myXmlType = XmlProvider<"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><ROOT><level1 name="level1Name1" x="8"><level2 name="level2Name1" a="8" b="104" /><level2 name="level2Name2" a="85" b="140" /></level1><level1 name="level1Name2" x="10"><level2 name="level2Name3" a="50" b="500" /><level2 name="level2Name4" a="376" b="1065" /><level2 name="level2Name5" a="10" b="100" /><level2 name="level2Name6" a="700" b="700" /></level1><level1 name="level1Name3" x="7"><level2 name="level2Name7" a="502" b="66" /></level1></ROOT>""">

let myXml = myXmlType.Parse("""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><ROOT><level1 name="level1Name1" x="8"><level2 name="level2Name1" a="8" b="104" /><level2 name="level2Name2" a="85" b="140" /></level1><level1 name="level1Name2" x="10"><level2 name="level2Name3" a="50" b="500" /><level2 name="level2Name4" a="376" b="1065" /><level2 name="level2Name5" a="10" b="100" /><level2 name="level2Name6" a="700" b="700" /></level1><level1 name="level1Name3" x="7"><level2 name="level2Name7" a="502" b="66" /></level1></ROOT>""")

let howToDoIt =
    myXml.GetLevel1s()
    |> Seq.collect (fun L1 -> L1.GetLevel2s())
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun L2 -> L2.b = L1.x * L2.a) // *REMARK
    |> function
    | None -> ""
    | Some L2 -> L2.Name
```

**REMARK*: L1.x obviously won't work, but I want to achieve something similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use `Seq.tryPick` on the `L1`s, with the inner function searching among the children of the current `L1`:

```
myXml.GetLevel1s()
|> Seq.tryPick (fun L1 ->
    L1.GetLevel2s()
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun L2 -> L2.b = L1.x * L2.a))
|> function
| None -> ""
| Some L2 -> L2.Name
```

Comment: +1 As a side note, I'd probably replace the last three lines with a temporary variable `optName` and then use the `defaultArg` function.

Comment: We can always go one level deeper until we reach F# Limbo.